# Implementing Collections.sort using a comparator defined in a class nested in another class

Tags: java, collections, comparator, inner-classes

I have a particular class, let's call it ClassX. ClassX is a simple little class; it has a few data members, a constructor, and (less simply) a nested class. The nested class is specifically for defining a comparator, and is written in this way:

```
public static Comparator<ClassX> classXComparator = new Comparator<ClassX>()
{
    public int compare(ClassX x1, ClassX x2)
    {
        //code that compares two data members and returns -1 for x2>x1, 1 for x1>x2, 
        //0 for x1 = x2
    }
}
```

I also have another class, let's call it ClassA. ClassA is the main class of my project, and has an ArrayList of ClassXs called entries. I want to call Collections.sort() on entries; however, I just can't figure out how. The list of things I've tried includes:

- `Collections.sort(entries, ClassX.classXComparator.compare(ClassX, ClassX));`
- `Collections.sort(entries, ClassX.classXComparator.compare(ClassX a, ClassX b));`
- `Collections.sort(entries, classXComparator.compare());`
- `Collections.sort(entries, ClassX.compare(ClassX, ClassX));`

I'm stumped. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

To understand what's happening look at the declaration of `classXComparator`:

```
public static Comparator<ClassX> classXComparator = <something>
```

This declares `classXComparator` as a `static` field of type `Comparator<ClassX>`, which is precisely the type of the second argument of `sort(...)`. Therefore, the invocation of `sort` should be as follows:

```
Collections.sort(entries, ClassX.classXComparator);
```